# Can I dynamically change the 'likeable' object for the Facebook Like Button?

Tags: javascript, facebook-like

I have a photo lightbox where each photo can be Facebook liked.

What would be the most effective way of making the Facebook like button to like the displayed photo without the URL changing, or does the URL need to change in order for this to work? For example, can I just change the Facebook meta tags to contain the current photo's info, or would this still fail as the URL doesn't change?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The facebook JS SDK provides a very useful method called `FB.XFBML.parse` you can use it to "re-parse" XFBML code that was generated "on the fly" - for example - a different like button for each AJAX call made - like in your example.
All the information you need can be found [on this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/) from the [Facebook javascript SDK documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)